# Dart circumvent dart:io http parsing error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with a 3rd party device that hosts its own webserver. I am trying to hit this webserver with a get request. It succeeds with curl, or postman, but the get response is interpreted as erroneous from dart:io. This code receives an error:  `HttpException (HttpException: Failed to parse HTTP, 32 is expected to be a Hex digit, uri = http://10.22.2.214/settings/time)`

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var request = await HttpClient().openUrl(
    'get',
    Uri.parse('http://10.22.2.214/settings/time'),
  );
  var response = await request.close();
  var chunks = [];
  var stringStream = response.transform(Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed: true));
  // stringStream = stringStream.handleError((e) => null);

  await for (var chunk in stringStream) {
    chunks.add(chunk);
  }
  print(chunks);
}
```

The request succeeds and gives the full expected response in a number of other places. IE: Python 3+(requests), Postman, Curl, Google Chrome. So I know it is possible to parse the request successfully.

Anyone have any ideas on how I might circumvent the error? I would like to stay in dart/flutter if possible. I know I could run python code with a package like [starflut](https://pub.dev/packages/starflut), but its a lot of setup for a single request.

Additional Info:

Ignoring the error view the `handleError` function does not seem to keep the stream open to receive the rest of the response.

The webserver fails to properly implement HTTP 1.1 by incorrectly using the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header.

Http and Dio both use dart:io under the hood and both gave me the same error.

result from `curl -D - http:/10.22.2.214/settings/time`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Connection: close
Accept-Ranges: none
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=500">
<meta charset="utf-8"><title>Time Settings</title><script>
var d=document;function H(){window.open("https://github.com/Aircoookie/WLED/wiki/Settings#time-settings")}function B(){window.open("/settings","_self")}function S(){BTa(),GetV(),Cs(),FC()}function gId(t){return d.getElementById(t)}function Cs(){gId("cac").style.display="none",gId("coc").style.display="block",gId("ccc").style.display="none",gId("ca").selected&&(gId("cac").style.display="block"),gId("cc").selected&&(gId("coc").style.display="none",gId("ccc").style.display="block"),gId("cn").selected&&(gId("coc").style.display="none")}function BTa(){var t="<tr><th>Active</th><th>Hour</th><th>Minute</th><th>Preset</th><th>M</th><th>T</th><th>W</th><th>T</th><th>F</th><th>S</th><th>S</th></tr>";for(i=0;i<8;i++)for(t+='<tr><td><input name="W'+i+'" id="W'+i+'" type="number" style="display:none"><input id="W'+i+'0" type="checkbox"></td><td><input name="H'+i+'" type="number" min="0" max="24"></td><td><input name="N'+i+'" type="number" min="0" max="59"></td><td><input name="T'+i+'" type="number" min="0" max="250"></td>',j=1;j<8;j++)t+='<td><input id="W'+i+j+'" type="checkbox"></td>';for(t+='<tr><td><input name="W8" id="W8" type="number" style="display:none"><input id="W80" type="checkbox"></td><td>Sunrise<input name="H8" value="255" type="hidden"></td><td><input name="N8" type="number" min="-59" max="59"></td><td><input name="T8" type="number" min="0" max="250"></td>',j=1;j<8;j++)t+='<td><input id="W8'+j+'" type="checkbox"></td>';for(t+='<tr><td><input name="W9" id="W9" type="number" style="display:none"><input id="W90" type="checkbox"></td><td>Sunset<input name="H9" value="255" type="hidden"></td><td><input name="N9" type="number" min="-59" max="59"><td><input name="T9" type="number" min="0" max="250"></td>',j=1;j<8;j++)t+='<td><input id="W9'+j+'" type="checkbox"></td>';gId("TMT").innerHTML=t}function FC(){for(j=0;j<8;j++)for(i=0;i<10;i++)gId("W"+i+j).checked=gId("W"+i).value>>j&1}function Wd(){for(a=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],i=0;i<10;i++){for(m=1,j=0;j<8;j++)a[i]+=gId("W"+i+j).checked*m,m*=2;gId("W"+i).value=a[i]}}function addRow(t,e,n,i){var d=gId("macros"),u=d.rows.length,c=d.insertRow(u);document.createElement("td");c.insertCell(0).innerHTML=`Button ${t}:`,c.insertCell(1).innerHTML=`<input name="MP${t}" type="number" min="0" max="250" value="${e}" required>`,c.insertCell(2).innerHTML=`<input name="ML${t}" type="number" min="0" max="250" value="${n}" required>`,c.insertCell(3).innerHTML=`<input name="MD${t}" type="number" min="0" max="250" value="${i}" required>`}function GetV() {
d.Sf.NT.checked=1;d.Sf.NS.value="Ntp-wwv.nist.gov";d.Sf.CF.checked=0;d.Sf.TZ.selectedIndex=6;d.Sf.UO.value=0;d.Sf.LN.value="0.00";d.Sf.LT.value="0.00";d.getElementsByClassName("times")[0].innerHTML="2106-2-7, 12:39:17 AM";d.Sf.OL.selectedIndex=0;d.Sf.O1.value=0;d.Sf.O2.value=0;d.Sf.OM.value=0;d.Sf.OS.checked=0;d.Sf.O5.checked=0;d.Sf.CX.value="HHMMSS";d.Sf.CB.checked=1;d.Sf.CE.checked=0;d.Sf.CY.value=22;d.Sf.CI.value=1;d.Sf.CD.value=1;d.Sf.CH.value=2;d.Sf.CM.value=1;d.Sf.CS.value=1;d.Sf.A0.value=0;d.Sf.A1.value=0;d.Sf.MC.value=0;d.Sf.MN.value=0;addRow(0,0,0,0);addRow(1,0,0,0);addRow(2,0,0,0);addRow(3,0,0,0);d.Sf.H0.value=9;d.Sf.N0.value=24;d.Sf.T0.value=1;d.Sf.W0.value=255;d.Sf.H1.value=9;d.Sf.N1.value=38;d.Sf.T1.value=2;d.Sf.W1.value=255;d.Sf.H2.value=0;d.Sf.N2.value=0;d.Sf.T2.value=0;d.Sf.W2.value=255;d.Sf.H3.value=0;d.Sf.N3.value=0;d.Sf.T3.value=0;d.Sf.W3.value=255;d.Sf.H4.value=0;d.Sf.N4.value=0;d.Sf.T4.value=0;d.Sf.W4.value=255;d.Sf.H5.value=0;d.Sf.N5.value=0;d.Sf.T5.value=0;d.Sf.W5.value=255;d.Sf.H6.value=0;d.Sf.N6.value=0;d.Sf.T6.value=0;d.Sf.W6.value=255;d.Sf.H7.value=0;d.Sf.N7.value=0;d.Sf.T7.value=0;d.Sf.W7.value=255;d.Sf.N8.value=0;d.Sf.T8.value=0;d.Sf.W8.value=0;d.Sf.N9.value=0;d.Sf.T9.value=0;d.Sf.W9.value=0;}</script><style>body{font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;text-align:center;background:#222;color:#fff;line-height:200%;margin:0}hr{border-color:#666}a{color:#28f;text-decoration:none}.btn,button{background:#333;color:#fff;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;border:.3ch solid #333;display:inline-block;font-size:20px;margin:12px 8px 8px;padding:1px 6px;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none}.lnk{border:0}.helpB{text-align:left;position:absolute;width:60px}input{background:#333;color:#fff;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;border:.5ch solid #333}input:disabled{color:#888}input[type=number]{width:4em;margin:2px}input[type=number].xxl{width:100px}input[type=number].xl{width:85px}input[type=number].l{width:63px}input[type=number].m{width:56px}input[type=number].s{width:49px}input[type=number].xs{width:42px}input[type=checkbox]{transform:scale(1.5);margin-right:10px}select{background:#333;color:#fff;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;border:.5ch solid #333}td{padding:2px}.d5{width:4.5em!important}#toast{opacity:0;background-color:#444;border-radius:5px;bottom:64px;color:#fff;font-size:17px;padding:16px;pointer-events:none;position:fixed;text-align:center;z-index:5;transform:translateX(-50%);max-width:90%;left:50%}#toast.show{opacity:1;background-color:#264;animation:fadein .5s,fadein .5s 2.5s reverse}#toast.error{opacity:1;background-color:#b21;animation:fadein .5s}</style></head><body onload="S()"><form
 id="form_s" name="Sf" method="post" onsubmit="Wd()"><div class="helpB"><button 
type="button" onclick="H()">?</button></div><button type="button" onclick="B()">
Back</button><button type="submit">Save</button><hr><h2>Time setup</h2>
Get time from NTP server: <input type="checkbox" name="NT"><br><input name="NS" 
maxlength="32"><br>Use 24h format: <input type="checkbox" name="CF"><br>
Time zone: <select name="TZ"><option value="0" selected="selected">GMT(UTC)
</option><option value="1">GMT/BST</option><option value="2">CET/CEST</option>
<option value="3">EET/EEST</option><option value="4">US-EST/EDT</option><option 
value="5">US-CST/CDT</option><option value="6">US-MST/MDT</option><option 
value="7">US-AZ</option><option value="8">US-PST/PDT</option><option value="9">
CST(AWST)</option><option value="10">JST(KST)</option><option value="11">
AEST/AEDT</option><option value="12">NZST/NZDT</option><option value="13">
North Korea</option><option value="14">IST (India)</option><option value="15">
CA-Saskatchewan</option><option value="16">ACST</option><option value="17">
ACST/ACDT</option><option value="18">HST (Hawaii)</option><option value="19">
NOVT (Novosibirsk)</option><option value="20">AKST/AKDT (Anchorage)</option>
<option value="21">MX-CST/CDT</option></select><br>UTC offset: <input name="UO" 
type="number" min="-65500" max="65500" required> seconds (max. 18 hours)<br>
Current local time is <span class="times">unknown</span>.<br>Latitude (N): 
<input name="LT" type="number" min="-66.6" max="66.6" step="0.01">
 Longitude (E): <input name="LN" type="number" min="-180" max="180" step="0.01">
<div id="sun" class="times"></div><h3>Clock</h3>Clock Overlay: <select 
name="OL" onchange="Cs()"><option value="0" id="cn" selected="selected">None
</option><option value="1" id="ca">Analog Clock</option><option value="2">
Single Digit Clock</option><option value="3" id="cc">Cronixie Clock</option>
</select><br><div id="coc">First LED: <input name="O1" type="number" min="0" 
max="255" required> Last LED: <input name="O2" type="number" min="0" max="255" 
required><br><div id="cac">12h LED: <input name="OM" type="number" min="0" 
max="255" required><br>Show 5min marks: <input type="checkbox" name="O5"><br>
</div>Seconds (as trail): <input type="checkbox" name="OS"><br></div><div 
id="ccc">Cronixie Display: <input name="CX" maxlength="6"><br>
Cronixie Backlight: <input type="checkbox" name="CB"><br></div>Countdown Mode: 
<input type="checkbox" name="CE"><br>Countdown Goal:<br>Year: 20 <input 
name="CY" type="number" min="0" max="99" required> Month: <input name="CI" 
type="number" min="1" max="12" required> Day: <input name="CD" type="number" 
min="1" max="31" required><br>Hour: <input name="CH" type="number" min="0" 
max="23" required> Minute: <input name="CM" type="number" min="0" max="59" 
required> Second: <input name="CS" type="number" min="0" max="59" required><br>
<h3>Macro presets</h3><b>Macros have moved!</b><br><i>
Presets now also can be used as macros to save both JSON and HTTP API commands.
<br>Just enter the preset id below!</i> <i>
Use 0 for the default action instead of a preset</i><br>Alexa On/Off Preset: 
<input name="A0" type="number" min="0" max="250" required> <input name="A1" 
type="number" min="0" max="250" required><br>Countdown-Over Preset: <input 
name="MC" type="number" min="0" max="250" required><br>
Timed-Light-Over Presets: <input name="MN" type="number" min="0" max="250" 
required><br><h3>Button actions</h3><table style="margin:0 auto" id="macros">
<thead><tr><td>push<br>switch</td><td>short<br>on-&gt;off</td><td>long<br>
off-&gt;on</td><td>double<br>N/A</td></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table><a 
href="https://github.com/Aircoookie/WLED/wiki/Macros#analog-button" 
target="_blank">Analog Button setup</a><h3>Time-controlled presets</h3><div 
style="display:inline-block"><table id="TMT"></table></div><hr><button 
type="button" onclick="B()">Back</button><button type="submit">Save</button>
</form></body></html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a package like [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to make the http request instead of writing from scratch?

Comment: Http uses dart:io under the hood. It failed (dio also)

Comment: Could you post a full raw HTTP response from your server? I suspect some of the headers are not correctly formatted and the other libs are ignoring this problem.

Comment: Yeah, your HTTP response are invalid for chunked Transfer-Encoding. If you read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#directives . You can see it should have "length of the current chunk in hexadecimal format" and then "followed by '\r\n' and then the chunk itself, followed by another '\r\n'.". There are no length to be found in your posted example. The webserver you are communicating with seems to fail in implementing HTTP 1.1.

Comment: Haha, I am not surprised. I am pretty sure those who implemented it are integrated systems software engineers and lack the knowledge of the standards. That said, It would be best if I could ignore the headers like the other libs do so I don't have to maintain my own branch of the 3rd parties source code (we don't have the personnel for that). Any clue if thats possible? (i mean I also lack the knowledge of the standards who am I kidding.)

Comment: It is not something you can just ignore since it is really an important part of the builtin Dart HTTP parser. The value are used here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/011079cc3bde394c326657c3788db43250cca3b3/sdk/lib/_http/http_parser.dart#L774 and validated here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/011079cc3bde394c326657c3788db43250cca3b3/sdk/lib/_http/http_parser.dart#L1046 . So the value are really used by the HTTP lib to know how much data it should read. It would require some rewriting of the logic to ignore this value and instead just guess based on headers.

Comment: Another issue here is that by not having the size, the data are not able to contain `\r\n` since this is used to split the data. So if other libs works, it then just works because the data does not contain `\r\n`. But that is also really not something I would declare stable. :)

Comment: If the endpoint supports HTTP/2, you might be lucky that they have implemented that part more correctly. You can use: https://pub.dev/packages/http2 to make the connection then.

Comment: I see. I appreciate your time. Thanks for the advice. I will see what I can do with the webservers source code. :) Maybe they will accept a merge request so I don't have to maintain my own branch after fixing it.